Obtaining list of all EPSG code for a single location on map
There are APIs like https://epsg.org/info-api.html, maptiler which takes text input like "San francisco" and returns EPSG codes, but the problem, is I am not able to find a library or a tool which takes in [lat,long] and gives me EPSG for that location like https://epsg.org/search/map. I hope, if someone can share any such tool / API for this usecase (or) should I have to host the EPSG dataset myself and query it ( I am not sure if it is possible)
CONTEXT : I am trying to help users convert their point cloud data from one CRS to another for their GIS workflows. Instead of actually asking the users the EPSG code for the target CRS, I thought of an intuitive way, where they could pick a location on map, after which I can show them list of all EPSG codes for that location (exactly like this https://epsg.org/search/map, https://crs-explorer.proj.org).
Alternatively, I have thought of another approach where I "reverse geocode" the lat,long values to obtain the location information and pass these as inputs to get EPSG codes. But I dont want the additional responsibility of accurately picking the right location information (city vs state) from the reverse geocoded data to find EPSG code

Does this link help you - https://epsg.io/

Once you do a search o the epsg.org/search/map page, the "Export" button goes to a URL that has a point or box etc embedded in it, and downloads an XLSX file. You can manually construct this URL for any point and use it like an API. Is that workable? Check the sites Ts+Cs that this usage is allowed, and maybe contact them to check...

IIRC the epsg database contains valid geographic domains for all the crs , you could index those in a spatial index and do a lookup

@CyrilMikhalchenko Do they allow us to use lat,long as inputs to obtain the relevant EPSG code. When I checked their documentation, there is a search API which takes in a "text" input and gives the list of epsg codes. https://docs.maptiler.com/cloud/api/coordinates/ Am I wrong here ?

Judging by the examples provided on their website, using the API key, I think you can. But it's always better to contact the software developers directly for more information....

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/376874/144357
In pyproj 3, you can query the PROJ database for CRS in a specific location: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/latest/api/database.html#pyproj-database-query-crs-info
>>> from pyproj.database import query_crs_info, query_utm_crs_info
>>> from pyproj.aoi import AreaOfInterest
>>> bl_lat, bl_lon = 40.64423086189233, -74.0307935018417
>>> aoi = AreaOfInterest(bl_lon, bl_lat, bl_lon, bl_lat)
>>> crs_list = query_crs_info(auth_name="EPSG", pj_types="PROJECTED_CRS", area_of_interest=aoi)
>>> len(crs_list)
46
>>> pprint([(crs.name, crs.code) for crs in crs_list if "NAD83(2011)" in crs.name])
[('NAD83(2011) / UTM zone 18N', '6347'),
 ('NAD83(2011) / Conus Albers', '6350'),
 ('NAD83(2011) / New Jersey', '6526'),
 ('NAD83(2011) / New Jersey (ftUS)', '6527'),
 ('NAD83(2011) / New York Long Island', '6538'),
 ('NAD83(2011) / New York Long Island (ftUS)', '6539')]
>>> pprint([(crs.name, crs.code) for crs in crs_list if "NAD83 " in crs.name])
[('NAD83 / New York Long Island (ftUS)', '2263'),
 ('NAD83 / UTM zone 18N', '26918'),
 ('NAD83 / New Jersey', '32111'),
 ('NAD83 / New York Long Island', '32118'),
 ('NAD83 / Statistics Canada Lambert', '3347'),
 ('NAD83 / New Jersey (ftUS)', '3424'),
 ('NAD83 / Canada Atlas Lambert', '3978'),
 ('NAD83 / BLM 18N (ftUS)', '4438'),
 ('NAD83 / Conus Albers', '5070')]
>>> utm_crs_list = query_utm_crs_info(area_of_interest=aoi)
>>> pprint([(crs.name, crs.code) for crs in utm_crs_list])
[('NAD27 / UTM zone 18N', '26718'),
 ('NAD83 / UTM zone 18N', '26918'),
 ('WGS 72 / UTM zone 18N', '32218'),
 ('WGS 72BE / UTM zone 18N', '32418'),
 ('WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N', '32618'),
 ('NAD83(NSRS2007) / UTM zone 18N', '3725'),
 ('NAD83(HARN) / UTM zone 18N', '3748'),
 ('NAD83(2011) / UTM zone 18N', '6347')]


Below is a very basic map interface that uses folium, streamlit and streamlit-folium to grab the lat, lon coordinates from mouse clicks to query the proj database as per @snowman2's answer:
Environment used:
conda create -n projmap -c conda-forge streamlit folium streamlit-folium pandas pyproj

Code for projmap.py:
import folium as fl
from folium.plugins import LocateControl

import pandas as pd
from pyproj.database import query_crs_info, query_utm_crs_info
from pyproj.aoi import AreaOfInterest
from streamlit_folium import st_folium
import streamlit as st


m = fl.Map(max_bounds=True, min_zoom=1, min_lat=-90,max_lat=90, min_lon=-180, max_lon=180)

# Allow finding users current location
l = LocateControl(auto_start=True)
m.add_child(l)

map = st_folium(m, height=400)

coords = map.get("last_clicked")

if coords is not None:
    # Handle longitude bounds when zoomed out
    if coords["lng"] < -180:
        coords["lng"] = coords["lng"] % 360
    elif coords["lng"] > 180:
        coords["lng"] = coords["lng"] % -360

    aoi = AreaOfInterest(coords["lng"], coords["lat"], coords["lng"], coords["lat"])
    crs_list = query_crs_info(auth_name="EPSG", pj_types="PROJECTED_CRS", area_of_interest=aoi)
    crs_list = [(f"https://epsg.io/{crs.code}", crs.name) for crs in crs_list]
    crs_df = pd.DataFrame(crs_list, columns=('EPSG', 'Name'))

    st.subheader(f"Coordinates (lat, lon):")
    st.write(f"{coords["lat"]:.4f}, {coords["lng"]:.4f}")

    st.subheader(f"Coordinate Systems found:")
    st.dataframe(
        crs_df,
         hide_index=True,
         column_config={
            "EPSG": st.column_config.LinkColumn(
                display_text=r"https:\/\/epsg\.io\/(.*)"
            )
         }
    )

Running the map:
conda activate projmap
streamlit run projmap.py

Example output:

